# A problem with continuous functions and limits

Tags: real-analysis

The question:
Given is a continuous function f, from R^n to R and a point c in R^n.
Let f(c) > 0 and let m be in R such that 0 < m < f(c). Show that there exists a delta > 0 so that |x-c| < delta implies that f(x) > m.

My take:
We know that |x-c| < delta and because of continuity of f we can say that |f(x) - f(c)| < ε. I don't realy know what to do from here, I have been thinking for hours but I am just stuck. I thought that maybe saying that there is a z so that f(z) = m and letting delta be this point z might work but I have no idea how to test this theory.

Comment: Probably $f$ is assumed to be continuous ?

Comment: yes it is sorry

Comment: Do you understand the definition of continuity of $f$ at $c$? Can you visualize the situation?

Comment: Yeah, if x approaches c then f(x)=f(c)

Comment: That's roughly right, but the precise epsilon-delta definition is important here.

Comment: Well we know that 0 < m < f(c) is limx>c f(x), so if |x-c|<delta than |f(x)-f(c)|<epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand and keep track of the quantifier phrases "for all" and "there exists", which are critically important in mathematical language.

The definition of "$f$ is continuous at $c$" is: **for all** $\epsilon>0$, **there exists** $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$, if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. The "for all" means you can pick whatever value of $\epsilon$ you want (as long as it's positive), and the "there exists" means that continuity then "gives you" a $\delta$ value. This value ensures that $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ units of $f(c)$ as long as $x$ is within $\delta$ units of $c$. In other words, you can make $f(x)$ as close to $f(c)$ as you want just by making $x$ close enough to $c$.

Now in your problem, the task is to find (i.e. show that **there exists**) a region where $f(x)>m$. Continuity helps ensure that $f(x)$ is close to $f(c)$ ...is that helpful? Yes, because we're given that $f(c)>m$. So if $f(x)$ is close enough to $f(c)$, it will be larger than $m$ too. How close does it need to be? Closer than the difference $f(c)-m$, of course.

So we choose $\epsilon=f(c)-m$; continuity guarantees us a corresponding $\delta$; now we know that whenever $|x-c|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. In particular, this forces $f(x)>f(c)-\epsilon$. Since we chose $\epsilon=f(c)-m$, this means $f(x)>f(c)-(f(c)-m)=m$, so we're done.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you explaination was very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

$0<m<f(c)\implies 0<f(c)-m$.

Let $\epsilon=[f(c)-m]/2$. By continuity, we have a $\delta$ so that $|x-c|<\delta \implies m-\epsilon<f(c)<m+\epsilon$

$m-[f(c)-m]/2=3m/2-f(c)/2$.

$m+[f(c)-m]/2=m/2+f(c)/2$.

$3m/2-f(c)/2<f(c)<m/2+f(c)/2$

$3m-f(c)<2f(c)<m+f(c)$

$3m<3f(c)<m+2f(c)$

$[m<f(c)]<m/3+(2/3)f(c)$

So if we have a $\delta$ guaranteeing that value of $\epsilon$, which we are guaranteed by continuity a  $\delta$.